# Kappa (interrater agreement) alternative for count-based data which results in inflated agreement at lower counts?

Tags: reliability, cohens-kappa, agreement-statistics

I have a data set where four coders are rating 800 items on various attributes. This is achieved by reporting a count of the prevalence of each attribute, e.g. rater 1 thinks attribute A appears in item 1 5 times, attribute B appears 4 times, etc.

I want to calculate the agreement between my raters; however, I am nervous that traditional measures of kappa (Cohen's, etc.) would be misleadingly inflated given that agreement is much more likely to happen at lower counts. Notably, over half of the counts are zero -- if an attribute simply does not appear in an item, you are essentially guaranteed a perfect agreement.

Alternatives I am considering involve filtering out the perfect agreements due to the zero counts; however, I am wondering if there is some alternative method to calculating kappa specifically for count-based data, e.g. a proportion-based one that weights numerical differences in rating vs. the magnitude of the rating, such that a disagreement of 5 vs. 15 wouldn't be much smaller than a disagreement of 10 vs. 50.

Thank you!

EDIT: Was looking for Krippendorff's alpha!